# JPA Store object as string identifier only

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Let’s say we have a User

```
@Entity
class User {
    String name;
    …
    ExternalSystemObject eso;
    …
}
```

Is there an easy way to store the `ExternalSystemObject` as it’s identifier only (e.g. a column `eso_id: String` for example) and provide a mapper to map the ID back to an object when retrieving the data?

Obviously I can define the field as `String` in the model but that would involve creating another object to represent the original required data model.

I thought that is a simple commonly desired behaviour but couldn’t find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do that using a `javax.persistence.Converter;`.

```
@Converter
public class ExternalSystemObjectConverter implements AttributeConverter<ExternalSystemObject, String> {

    @Override public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ExternalSystemObjectConverter eso) {
        return eso.getId();
    }

    @Override public ExternalSystemObjectConverter convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        // retrieve or build eso
        return eso;
    }
}
```